# Trigger invalid event jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

Can "the invalid popup" be triggered by custom function without submit a form?

Invalid popup -> https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/tutorials/constraintvalidation/ChromeForAndroid.png

[image]

Comment: That's HTML5 validation, nothing to do with jQuery. But you can use `.on('keyup')` event.

Comment: No, you can't trigger the popup, you can only trigger validation

Comment: You can perform the valodation on 'keyup', 'keydown', 'input' events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an `input`

```
<input type="text" id="input_id">
```

**using  jquery you can perform this validation as :**

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#input_id", function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '' )
    {
        /* show error message here */
    }
});
```

**Or if you want to use pure JavaScript, you can use :**

```
var el = document.getElementById('input_id'); 

el.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    validate_me(this);
}, false);

function validate_me(e)
{
     if(e.value == '')
     {
          /* error message here */
     }
}
```

**If you want the `html5` only solution :**

To check whether a certain field is valid, use:

```
$('#myField')[0].checkValidity() // returns true/false
```

To check if the form is valid, use:

```
$('#myForm')[0].checkValidity() // returns true/false
```

If you want to display the native error messages that some browsers have (such as Chrome), unfortunately the only way to do that is by submitting the form, like this:

```
var $myForm = $('#myForm')
if (!$myForm[0].checkValidity()) {
    // If the form is invalid, submit it. The form won't actually submit;
   // this will just cause the browser to display the native HTML5 error messages.
  $myForm.find(':submit').click()
}
```

Keep in mind that HTML5 validation is not supported in all browsers.